# Олимпиадная задача С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Помогите решить задачу на С++

> Шахматная ассоциация выдала своим сотрудникам телефоны, номера на которых можно набирать только ходом коня, причем номер не может начинаться с цифры 8 и 0

```
 7 8 9
 4 5 6
 1 2 3
   0
```

Вводится число `N` `(1 <= N <= 100)`, обозначающее длину номера.
Какое количество разных номеров данной длины можно набрать?

Т.е. для `N = 3`
вариации могут быть такими: `1-6-7 1-6-1 2-7-6` и т.д.

Comment: форматирование текста? не, не слышал

Comment: Лошадью ходи!

Comment: @risonyo, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: да, примерно так и просчитывал таблицу возможных ходов и т.д. сложно было в виде кода реализовать

Comment: Быстрое возведение в степень для матрицы инцидентности графа ходов решает задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет логика, то решение должно быть таким. Старался написать максимально компактно, поэтому не во всех местах понятно идею алгоритма.

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char can_go[10][3]={{4,6,-1},{6,8,-1},{7,9,-1},{4,8,-1},{0,3,9},{-1,-1,-1},{0,1,7},{2,6,-1},{1,3,-1},{2,4,-1}};
    int end_digits[10]={0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},temp[10],s,n,i=0,j,l;
    for(cin>>n;i<n;i++)
      {
          for(j=s=0;j<10;s+=end_digits[j],temp[j++]=0);
          for(j=0;j<10;j++)
                for(l=(end_digits[j]?0:3);l<3;(can_go[j][l]!=-1?temp[can_go[j][l++]]+=end_digits[j]:l++));
          for(j=0;j<10;end_digits[j]=temp[j++]);
      }
    cout<<s<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Условный алгоритм:

1. *Обьявление переменных*. Создаётся массив `can_go`, строчка которого равна номерам ячеек, в которые мы можем переходить с ячейки под номером столбика (тоесть цифра, которая может идти после той, которая равна номеру столбца). Создаётся массив `end_digits`, который равен колличеству каждой цифры в конце номеров, созданых на данный момент (сам номер мы не запоминаем). Массив `temp` - временный, который будет переноситься в `end_digits`, переменная `s` - сумма (результат работы программы), `i`, `j`, `l` - для обхода массивов.
2. В начале каждого шага (колличество шагов - `n`) обнуляем массив `temp` и считаем сумму `s`.
3. Следующим шагом добавляем возможные номера телефонов. Добавляем их только если `end_digits[j]`>0, обходим каждый эллемент `can_go[j]` и добавляем к эллементу массива `temp` под номером, равным цифре номера телефона, в которую можем попасть, тоесть `can_go[j][l]`.
4. Переносим массив `temp` в `end_digits`.
5. Повторяем шаги 2-4 `n` раз и выводим результат - `s`.

Comment: Это решение "в лоб". На олимпиадах такое возможно, но поскольку предъявляются требования к памяти и времени выполнения, то они зачитываются только на простых тестах. На более сложных тестах - результат не зачтется.

Суть олимпиады - не решить задачу, а найти наилучшее решение.

Хотя в данном случае (поскольку N <= 100) - олимпиада для школьников, возможно это решение и проканает...

А что было бы, если бы N ~ 100000? Сколько бы времени выполнялось данное решение?

Comment: @BOPOH, я и не отрицаю, что решение "в лоб", здесь вроде как оно и требовалось :)

Именно на олимпиаде намного лучше было бы попробовать решить в лоб, потом проанализировать десяток тестов и найти закономерность. Показаный тут алгоритм работает "неэкономно" в плане памяти и времени.

Comment: А не... Я не правильно понял, че-то мне сначала показалось, что вы получаете все возможные номера и считаете их количество.

Алгоритм у вас почти верный. "Почти" - не увидел где из конечного результата вычитаются суммы для 0 и 8. А потому и решение неверное.

И объяснение хромает))

Comment: @BOPOH, в любом случае, попробовать найти закономерность стоило бы — тогда можно максимально упростить алгоритм.

А насчёт 0 и 8 — спасибо, что подметили, я и забыл. Чтобы сделать невозможным начало номера с этих цифер — стоит просто изменить начальную установку массива `end_digits` на `{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}`.

Обьяснением не особо занимался, поэтому и написал, что алгоритм "условный" :)

Comment: @Crasher, опять не совсем правильно понял ваш алгоритм))

Когда сам решал - шел по-другому пути - добавлял цифры к началу. Решение было почти один-в-один ваше, вот только мне надо было в конце суммировать все, кроме 0 и 8, а у вас надо было исключить сразу)

"Условный" алгоритм - у вас это словесное описание данной реализации.

А алгоритм простой: опишу в следующем комментарии.

Comment: Рассмотрим номер a1a2...x.

a1... - цифры на месте 1, 2 и т.д. в номере. x - последняя цифра номера.

Будем хранить массив a[i], содержащий количество номеров оканчивающихся на цифру i.

Добавим к этому номеру (a1a2...x) цифру y.

Поскольку номеров, оканчивающихся на эту цифру y может быть несколько, то общее количество номеров, оканчивающихся на эту цифру y равно сумме значений a[i], где i - цифра номера, из которой мы можем попасть в цифру y.

Рассчитывая для каждого j = 1..N массив a[i] мы в конце получим количество всех номеров оканчивающихся на i.

Сумма элементов - и есть результат

Answer (score 7):

Задача на самом деле, если хорошо подумать, сводится к простому перебору и перемножению вариаций на разных этапах. **Приблизительный алгоритм:**

> 1) Нужно предварительно составить так
> называемые "таблицы возможных ходов"
> для каждой кнопки, например, для
> кнопки 1 имеем возможные ходы на 6, 6, 8 и
> 8, т.е на 6 и 8( две вариации ), для
> кнопки 2 имеем также два варианта
> хода: на 9 и на 7. Думаю, это понятно.
>
> 2) Вторым шагом вам необходимо
> поочередно от каждой кнопки ходить
> конем N раз( ходить по правилам составленной выше таблицы ), выводя при этом полный
> текущий путь от самой первой кнопки.
> Инкрементируя при этом определенный
> счетчик ходов.

Высчитывать количество вариаций ходов можно и иным способом, как уже многие поняли. Это делается банальным перемножением количества вариаций ходов от каждой кнопки.

**P.S**  Позже, думаю, смогу продемонстрировать уже доработанный алгоритм в действии, если вы сами не сможете...